# Error calling web service using vba

Tags: vba, web-services

I have the following code to make web service calls using VBA (word 2013). It was working fine with http until recently when the url changed to https.

```
Dim myRequest As Object
Set myRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
myRequest.setTimeouts 50000, 50000, 50000, 50000
myRequest.Open "GET", myURL, False
myRequest.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + EncodeToBase64("uid"+"pwd")
myRequest.Send
myRequest.waitForResponse (500)
```

When I changed the url from "http" to "https" it is giving this error.

> "Runtime error '-2147012739 (80072f7d)': An error occurred in the
>   secure channel support"

I have tried setting the client certificate (before Send method) but that didn't work. (I imported the certificate into my local computer and can see it in the certificate store)

```
myRequest.SetClientCertificate "LOCAL_MACHINE\Personal\Certificates\"
```

I really need to get this fixed. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

I remember having this problem,

> Microsoft ended support for Windows Server 2003 on July 14, 2015.
>   This change has affected your software updates and security options.

Have a look here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/938397